# Why doesn't the Pukwudgie appear in the updated version of the "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them" textbook?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, fantastic-beasts

The textbook that the Fantastic Beasts movie was based off of recently got an update, adding six new creatures and a new foreword. The symbols of three of the Ilvermorny Houses - Thunderbird, Horned Serpent, and Wampus, are all included in the new version. So why isn't the last one, Pukwudgie, also included? All of the creatures included in the update are originally from America, but Pukwudgies are also native to America, so would be eligible to be included.

Their description quoted from Pottermore (for now, the only source for information on Pukwudgies):

> The Pukwudgie is also native to America: a short, grey-faced,
>   large-eared creature distantly related to the European goblin.
>   Fiercely independent, tricky and not over-fond of humankind (whether
>   magical or mundane), it possesses its own powerful magic. Pukwudgies
>   hunt with deadly, poisonous arrows and enjoy playing tricks on humans.

So, why wasn't the Pukwudgie included in the updated version of "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them"?

Comment: Because JKR will need to sell new editions of the book when each of the next 4 movies will come out?

Comment: The updates were intended to be the minimal amount of changes needed for JKR to rework the charity agreement to give some of the profits to Lumos. She doesn't have the time or care to make any other additions.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Yeah, no kidding!

Answer (score 7):

**The Pukwudgie might be considered a being, not a beast.**

Some nonhumans aren't included in "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them" because they are classed as beings, not beasts - like goblins, vampires, and house-elves. Beings are defined as any creature that has sufficient intelligence to understand the laws of the magical community and to bear part of the responsibility in shaping those laws. Any creature that fits the criteria (unless they rejected 'being' status like the centaurs and merpeople or are too violent to be offered it like Acromantulas and Sphinxes) would be considered a being and therefore not included in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* since it only covers beasts.

The information we have about Pukwudgies comes from the Pottermore writing on the founding of Ilvermorny. The information we get from that about Pukwudgies, and one particular Pukwudgie called William, certainly could qualify them for 'being' status. William developed a friendship with Isolt that was similar to a friendship between two humans. If other Pukwudgies are anything like him, they are clearly intelligent enough to understand the laws of the magical community and to bear part of the responsibility in shaping those laws and merit a status of 'being'. Also, they may dislike humans, but Pukwudgies don't seem to be violent enough where that would disqualify them from 'being' status.